# Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category

Tags: boost, c++, visual-c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// ...

int main()
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;
    stream.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(60));

    // ...

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

А ошибка вот какая

> `'Error    3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::system::error_code::error_code(void)" (??0error_code@system@boost@@QAE@XZ)    c:\Users\Gen\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.obj  core2
> Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::'dynamic initializer for 'errno_ecat''(void)" (??__Eerrno_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)   c:\Users\Gen\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.obj  core2
> Error   5   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   c:\users\gen\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\core2.exe  1   1   core2'`

Comment: Сейчас скачал буст последний. Скопировал ваш код из поста и у меня он без единой ошибки скомпилировался. Главное укажите в настройках проекта папки в которых находятся заголовочные файлы и статические библиотеки.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте подключить библиотеку boost_system

Comment: Чтобы её подключить надо написать в header Так ? #include <boost_system>

Comment: нет. Не только. Нужно в библиотеках (libraries) добавить нужный файл.

Comment: Нет, надо где-то в свойствах проекта указать линковку библиотеки boost_system.dll

Comment: Кстати, хедер можно не указывать. Он уже включен в заголовках boost_asio, которая и зависит от этой библиотеки. Многие бустовские библиотеки от нее зависят.

Comment: Извините совсем не понял как добавить:( . Даже сделал поиск этой длл  в папке с бустом всеравно не нашол) можно обьяснить как для тупых ?)

Comment: Я с бустом только в лине работал. Там эта библиотека называется libboost_system.so или libboost_system.a. В винде должна быть что вроде boost_system.dll или boost_system.lib. Неужели нет?

Comment: Должен быть не DLL, а LIB файл после компиляции boost`a.

Comment: Разве для винды буст в виде dll не компилируется?

Comment: Ну, когда я с ним работал, то там только lib файлы получались. И только несколько библиотек из буста в либы компилились, остальная часть в основном заголовками идёт с шаблонами.

Answer (score 3):

По заголовку вижу что компилируете в студии.

Пропишите после хеадеров строку.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "boost_system.lib")
```

ну или как там называется данная библиотека.

А вообще вы сам boost компилировали?
В студии укажите пути к полученным библиотекам и будет вас счастье.

У меня данная библиотека называется:
libboost_system-vc100-mt-1_52.lib для Release
или
libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.lib для Debug

Comment: Да компилировал сам,путь вроде как указал ( не ругается на инклюды на сколько я понимаю) но даже вашим способом не видит  библеотеку

Comment: Ну если вы в настройках студии не указали путь к либ файлам, то в команде, которую я сверху написал, нужно вписать полный путь до библиотеки.

Comment: Если такой библиотеки нет (что очень странно), ее можно найти [здесь][1].

[1]: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/

Comment: [Как скомпилировать буст в dll.][1]
[1]: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Building-Boost-DLLs-td2695730.html